# Failure to set the height of Object Division with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I tend to make a division that `width = window.innerWidth; height = width/5;`
1/5 acturally is the background-image's height/weith ratio.
So I write the code as below.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>FORM</TITLE>
    <META CHARSET="gb2312" />
    <LINK REL="stylesheet" HREF="css/style.css" />
    <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
        function onload(){

            //innerWidth of the window 
            var window_innerWidth;
            //height of DIV#head
            var head_height;
            //DIV#head
            var head_div;
            //btn
            var left_btn;

            window_innerWidth=window.innerWidth;
            head_height=window_innerWidth*120/600;
            head_div=document.getElementById("head");
            left_btn=document.getElementById("head_left_btn");
            right_btn=document.getElementById("head_right_btn");

            if(head_div&&left_btn){
                head_div.width=window_innerWidth;
                head_div.height=head_height;


                alert(window_innerWidth+ " " +head_height + " " + head_div.height 
                    + " " + left_btn.height);

            }

        }
    </SCRIPT>

</HEAD>
<BODY onload="onload();">
    <DIV ID="head">
        <BUTTON ID="head_left_btn" class="btn_hide" TYPE="button"></BUTTON>
        <BUTTON ID="head_right_btn" class="btn_hide" TYPE="button"></BUTTON>
    </DIV>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

CSS:

```
#head{

background-image: url('../img/basic_.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}


.btn_hide{

width: 49.5%;
height: 100%;
opacity: 0.5;
}
```

The img I use as background is 600px*120px

What I am exactly doing is trying to make a head tabs. The problem is that while the width of the division goes right with javascript, the height doesn't. Though the output from alert shows the value of the height is right, the display of the page is not. Can anyone help here? Many thanks!

Comment: when you use Firebug/Chrome dev tools, what do you see for the actual height? (compared to the height you are expecting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
head_div.style.height = head_height + "px";
```

Comment: yeah, this works. but I'm confused. why height cannot access straight from division while width can? I've heard in HTML5 MOD, both width and height are property of element object, is that right?

Comment: @user1437534 I think you can use element.width or element.height to retrieve the height or width of that element. But when you want to set/write the property, I think you need to set directly using element.style